# UWP : Creating custom file name qualifiers makes no effect

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, screen-orientation

I have been trying to create a set of **custom** filename qualifiers to be able to load different views (XAMLs) depending on the screen orientation.

Following instructions found in Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast, I have set up the following qualifiers:

```
switch (orientation)
            {
                case EnumScreenOrientation.Landscape:
                    ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("Orientation", "Landscape", ResourceQualifierPersistence.LocalMachine);
                    break;
                case EnumScreenOrientation.Portrait:
                    ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("Orientation", "Portrait", ResourceQualifierPersistence.LocalMachine);
                    break;
                default:
                    ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("Orientation", "Landscape", ResourceQualifierPersistence.LocalMachine);
                    break;
            }
```

and then using it, in a project like so: **MainPage.Orientation-Portrait.xaml** or **MainPage.Orientation-Landscape.xaml**, whereas the default view is called MainPage.xaml.

I've also tried placing the xamls in the respective folders named: Orientation-Portrait and Orientation-Landscape. No effect. Views are never displayed.

I have tried the same with the Scale-125 and Scale-150 qualifiers and the mechanism is working.

Any suggestions/hints?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in the meantime:

ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue(...) can only override an existing qualifier. So, if you do:

```
ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("Custom", "Orientation-Landscape", ResourceQualifierPersistence.LocalMachine);
```

and set up a file name as: MainPage.Custom-Orientation-Ladscape, everything will work as expected.